# Change size of thumbnail after changing thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's probably something silly, however, with the code I have right now, I can edit non spoilered pictures on the fly, so that their thumbnail is changed to the spoiler thumbnail.

```
$("[src='path/to/original/thumbnail.jpg']").attr('src', "/static/spoiler.png")
```

however, the new the thumbnail retains the size of the original thumbnail, and my spoiler image looks extremely strange unless it's at the correct size.

How do I set the thumbnails size, after being changed to the spoiler image?

Width needs to be 94px, and height needs to be 128px, for the record.

Comment: Change those attributes too.

Comment: Create a separate class and use `.addClass`, `.removeClass` or `.toggleClass`, or if you want it in the HTML, do as alex says and change those attributes to, with `.attr('width', "94px")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how the image originally got its height and width. If via css, then simply change the height and width using JQuery's ".css()" method:

```
$("[src='/static/spoiler.png']").css('width', '94px').css('height': '128px');
```

Or if height and width is set via an attribute:

```
$("[src='/static/spoiler.png']").attr('width', "94px").attr('height', "128px")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the src as an attribute, set the property directly:

```
$("[src='path/to/original/thumbnail.jpg']").each(function(){
    this.src = "/static/spoiler.png";
});
```

Comment: That's a good point. You may want to make that a comment, though, because it doesn't answer his question directly.

Comment: Made it community wiki instead, so I can keep the nice formatting.